# CMake conditionally add Qt signals with preprocessor defines

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm working on a Qt project using CMake as a build system, but I'm running into a bit of an issue.

For debugging purposes, I want to add some extra buttons to my application, which means I also need associated signals/slots for those buttons to connect them. Since they're purely for debugging, though, I only want them included in the application if it's built in debug mode. To achieve this, I'm using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. For example, I have the following code:

```
IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "No CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE specified; defaulting to Debug mode.")
    SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
ENDIF()

STRING(TOLOWER "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_LOWER)
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_LOWER MATCHES debug)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DMYAPP_DEBUG")
ENDIF()
```

This seems to be working well. If I enable "verbose makefile," I see `-DMYAPP_DEBUG` being passed to the compiler just like it should be. This doesn't seem to work though, with `moc` files.

I'm using a rather recent version of CMake (i.e., >= 2.8.9), so I have the new `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` feature turned on. However, when I have a header file that contain:

```
#ifdef MYAPP_DEBUG
    void debugTriggered(bool);
#endif
```

I get the following when I start the application:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal MainMenu::debugTriggered(bool)
```

I'm assuming the reason for this is that the value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not taken into account when CMake is `AUTOMOC`-ing my sources. How can I alter my CMake build file to get this working?

Comment: Macros should be added using `add_definitions` and not via CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. Another problem is that your flags are messed up - you use cmake_**C**_flags to load values into cmake_**CXX**_flags

Comment: Adding the preprocessor definition with `add_definitions` instead of doing it by hand did the trick! Thanks! Add that as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros should be added using [`add_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aadd_definitions) and not via CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Another problem is that your flags are messed up - you use cmake_**C**_flags to load values into cmake_**CXX**_flags